# DJI SDK unable to resolve target

Tags: android, eclipse, dji-sdk

I am new to DJI mobile sdk, I am gonna go through the dji mobile device tutorial. Here is my question:
The tutorial is based on Eclipse 4.2.2,  Mobile sdk V2.1.0 and project build target is Android 4.4.2 using API 19.

What I have now is Eclipse 4.2.2,  Mobile SDK V2.4.1, and project build target is android 6.0 using API 23. But I received the following error

> [2015-12-03 15:24:03 - DJI-SDK-LIB] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'"

Whats wrong with it?

Does the project build target matter? Can I choose build target whatever I want?

What's the suggestion for choosing with Eclipse version, mobile sdk version and build target.

Answer (score 0):

DJI Mobile SDK has upgraded to 3.0 now, you can check this [link](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) for the latest DJI Android SDK. The sample code is developed based on Android Studio 1.5, doesn't support Eclipse any more.

For the FPVDemo Tutorial, it's developed based on Android Studio too, please check [here](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK/Android-FPVDemo) to get it.

Once you download the sample code or tutorial demo project and run them on Android Studio 1.5(You can download it from android developer website), you will know the build target info.

Hope this help!